# Implementing virtual threads without cheating

Tags: java, python, multithreading, gevent

In the [gevent tutorial](http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/) there's an example that looks like this:

```
import gevent

def foo():
    print('Running in foo')
    gevent.sleep(0)
    print('Explicit context switch to foo again')

def bar():
    print('Explicit context to bar')
    gevent.sleep(0)
    print('Implicit context switch back to bar')

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(foo),
    gevent.spawn(bar),
])
```

and the output is

```
Running in foo
Explicit context to bar
Explicit context switch to foo again
Implicit context switch back to bar
```

I've tested it and seen for myself that it works.  A friend of mine claims this is run entirely within a single thread. Except that I can't think of any implementation of gevent.sleep(0) which doesn't boil down to some form of "cheating" (ie: Swap the top two stack frames etc.)

Can someone explain how this works?  If this were Java (or at least some language where that kind of stack manipulation is forbidden), would this be possible? (again, without using multiple threads).

Comment: `Swap the top two stack frames ` - This is how thread actually work so how is that cheating?  It is possible in Java with a library which support continuations.

Comment: Can a Java library which supports continuations be implemented in pure Java?  If so, then it's not cheating.

Comment: There are a couple which use instrumentation.

Comment: It adds extra code so the stack can be saved and restored. I don't image it's very fast which is why you are generally better off using real threads more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed runs on only 1 thread. gevent uses greenlets, which are coroutines, not threads. There is only 1 stack at each given time (unless you use multithreading, and then use greenlets in each threads).

In your example above, whenever you call sleep or joinall, the current coroutine (greenlet) actually yields to the hub. Think about the hub as a central dispatcher, responsible to decide which coroutine will run next.

To convince yourself of that, remove the gevent.sleep(0) call, and you'll see that it behaves differently.

Note that unlike threads, the execution is deterministic, so if you run the program twice, it will execute in the exact same order.

Comment: But how is it implemented?  What's the trick?  Are they messing with the interpreter or can this be done purely in native python?

Comment: It is written in C. It's like a "GO TO", which jumps directly to the hub.

Comment: I don't think C allows goto jumps from inside one function to inside another.  Would you mind adding some pseudocode to your answer?

Comment: Sorry, don't know enough about the exact implementation to add some pseudo-code